# How do I get the craft button to pop up on minecraft pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really enjoy minecraft. So I downloaded the pocket edition. But when I go into my inventory, there is no craft button. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure such a thing is existing? I dont find a craft button in the minecraft pocket edition (in the wiki)...

Comment: @Gerret there is a craft button, It just doesn't have a crafting grid

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your inventory

Comment: @Flaunting OHH you mean a button so you are able to craft things!! pff i thought that is a item in the pe

Comment: There used to be a button in the top left that said craft

Comment: If it's gone now how do you craft things now?

Comment: The full version lets you craft. The lite version does not.

Answer (score 3):

They have recently changed the inventory screen on Minecraft PE, the new screen looks like this, and runs using various tabs shown on the left.

[image]

You just need to click the bookshelf and it will open the crafting menu.

For reference the old screen looked like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 3 dote beside the hot bar (quick select). Then push the bookshelf button.